# How do i get tinymce to work in a livewire dialog modal

Tags: laravel, wysiwyg, laravel-livewire, tinymce-6

My issue, I have a modal form that shows when a button is clicked. The modal is showing but the description field is not rendering the tinymce editor. I have simplified my initial design down to a simple livewire component:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use App\Models\Job;
use Livewire\Component;

class TestModal extends Component
{
    public bool   $showingModal = false;
    public bool   $showButton = true;
    public string $description;
    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.test-modal');
    }

    public function showModal()
    {

        $this->showingModal = true;

    }

    public function hideModal()
    {
        $this->showingModal = false;
        $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('modalClosed');
    }

    public function submit()
    {
        $this->hideModal();
    }

}
```

and the blade:

```
<form wire:submit.prevent="submit()">
    <a
        class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm leading-5 text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100 focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-100 transition"
        wire:click="showModal()"
    >
        {{ __( 'Test' ) }}
    </a>

    <x-dialog-modal wire:model="showingModal" maxWidth="2xl" class="flex items-center">
        <x-slot name="title">
            Test Modal
        </x-slot>


        <x-slot name="content">
            <div class="md:col-span-1 flex justify-between">
                <div class="px-4 sm:px-0">
                    <h3 class="text-lg font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-50">Test Modal</h3>

                    <p class="mt-1 text-sm text-gray-600 dark:text-gray-200">
                        Please complete the fields.
                    </p>
                </div>

                <div class="col-span-6 sm:col-span-4">
                    <label class="block font-medium text-sm text-gray-700" for="description">
                        Job Description
                    </label>
                    <textarea
                        class="border-gray-300 focus:border-indigo-300 focus:ring focus:ring-indigo-200 focus:ring-opacity-50 rounded-md shadow-sm mt-1 block w-full dark-input"
                        id="description"
                        name="description"
                        wire:model.defer="description"
                        cols="40"
                        rows="5"
                    >
                    </textarea>
                    @error('description') <span class="text-danger">A Description is required</span> @enderror
                </div>

                <script src="https://cdn.tiny.cloud/1/xfigwgf559yj5t06awl1m42ptr8ubbr12sy00wtf1od3uh5p/tinymce/6/tinymce.min.js" referrerpolicy="origin"></script>
                <script>
                    tinymce.init({
                        selector: 'textarea#description', // Replace this CSS selector to match the placeholder element for TinyMCE
                        plugins: 'powerpaste advcode table lists checklist',
                        toolbar: 'undo redo | blocks| bold italic | bullist numlist checklist | code | table'
                    });

                    document.addEventListener('focusin', (e) => {
                        if (e.target.closest(".tox-tinymce-aux, .moxman-window, .tam-assetmanager-root") !== null) {
                            e.stopImmediatePropagation();
                        }
                    });
                </script>
            </div>
        </x-slot>

        <x-slot name="footer">
            <button class="text-off-white bg-green-500 dark:bg-green-700 focus:border-green-700 focus:ring-green-300 hover:bg-white dark:hover:bg-white hover:text-green-700 dark:hover:text-green-700 hover:shadow-md dark:hover:shadow-md border-solid border dark:border-off-white border-off-black ml-2 rounded-md font-semibold dark:font-bold text-xs uppercase inline-flex mb-4 items-center px-4 py-2 form-action-btn tracking-widest dark:pl-5 focus:outline-none focus:ring disabled:opacity-25 transition cursor-pointer" style="" type="submit">
                <span wire:loading.remove="" wire:target="formSubmit">
                    Submit
                </span>

                <span wire:loading="" wire:target="formSubmit">
                    Submitting...
                </span>
            </button>
        </x-slot>
    </x-dialog-modal>
</form>
```

So the modal is shown but the text area does not have any tinymce content. I do have bootstrap installed but this is not using that method being alpine and livewire.

Any ideas why it doesn't show? I have also tried to achieve this with ckeditor (same issue) and trix (showed but didn't allow more than one line so no use at all for this). If i render the description box on its own page it does work just not inside this modal. Has anyone managed to get something like this to work?